# Assign a hotkey to a "view" size in File Explorer

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, hotkeys

I (almost) always like looking at my (projects) folders in the size **Large Icons** and sometimes **List**. I'm always switching between those two and hardly ever anything else.

However, every folder that I open requires me to go to **View > {Size}** and it gets annoying to have to keep on doing it on my many folders.

---

> #### Is there a way I can assign a hotkey to a specific view size?

I could then simply assign <kbd>{key 1}</kbd> to **Large Icons** and <kbd>{key 2}</kbd> to **List** view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer to the following shortkey.

- For **Large Icons** you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>
- For **List** you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd>

This can be done in windows 10.

---

The same goes for the rest of the sizes:

> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+
>
> [image: screenshot of view sizes]

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> - Extra Large Icons
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> - Large Icons
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> - Medium Icons
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> - Small Icons
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd> - List
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd> - Details
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd> - Tiles
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd> - Content